# c# - SQL CE - TableAdaptor @@IDENTITY

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, tableadapter, dataadapter

i have the following Insert Statement:
In my table ID is Primary Key...

```
INSERT INTO Student(Name,Family,Address);
```

I create other query in TableAdapter called SelectID

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

now back to my Code:
i call Insert :

```
TableAdapter .Insert("Elli",Stuart","tt11");
Display("Record Added.....And Student ID is:" + TableAdapter .SelectID);
```

The problem is @@IDENTITY suppose to return me the ID but its not returning me anything here!
What im doing wrong?!

Comment: You need to call @@IDENTITY on the same open connection, see the Beth massi link in my comment to your other question...

Answer (score 0):

Since the TableAdapter.SelectID is a new command to the database, it might not relate to the insert that happened before.

Try this
http://forums.asp.net/post/1413442.aspx

Comment: One Question! Should i put my Insert Query inside Insert or Inside Select?!

Comment: Its the other way round - You are calling the Insert(), but you add the Select statement to it.